# React const keyword and creating component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React App, which seems to be creating a react components in the following manner:

```
const VariableName = () => {
<div>
<p>SomeText</p>
</div>
```

However, the materials available online show that the manner to create a React Component is

```
const VariableName = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <p>SomeText</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

What is the difference and how is the ReactApp that I am working on rendering the component?

Comment: This article contains a nice summary: http://frontendinsights.com/stateless-functional-components/

Answer (score -1):

The stateless components introduced in react 0.14 allows as don’t declare class and pass props to the component. Basically it's just a ES6 arrow function sintaksis

Comment: Thanks. By the end of the entire jsx file I have a master component which calls other components and renders it in divs. But comically a few components in between are not being rendered. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @DipeshKumarSukhani you have to check 'shouldComponentUpdate' lifecycle method.